# TIme complexity of various nested for loops

Tags: loops, for-loop, big-o, time-complexity, asymptotic-complexity

Time Complexity of a loop is considered as O(Logn) if the loop variables is divided / multiplied by a constant amount.

loop 1 ----

```
 for (int i = 1; i <=n; i *= c) 
{
   // some O(1) expressions
}
```

loop 2 -----

```
  for (int i = n; i > 0; i /= c) 
 {
   // some O(1) expressions
 }
```

Time Complexity of a loop is considered as O(LogLogn) if the loop variables is reduced / increased exponentially by a constant amount.

```
Here c is a constant greater than 1
```

loop 3 ----

```
for (int i = 2; i <=n; i = pow(i, c)) 
{ 
    // some O(1) expressions
}
```

loop 4 -----

```
 ////Here fun is sqrt or cuberoot or any other constant root
 for (int i = n; i > 0; i = fun(i)) 
{ 
   // some O(1) expressions
}
```

Can anyone explain me why it is by considering the number of times the inner loop executes in these loops?

If c=1 in loop 1 and loop 2 then it will run infinite times right but it is given as logarithimic time why?

how is it O(loglogN) in loop 3 and loop 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If c=1 in loop 1 and loop 2 then it will run infinite times right but it is given as logarithimic time why?

Yes you are right, if `c = 1` then we will get infinite loops for both case 1 and case 2, so the condition "*`c` is a[n integer] constant greater than 1*" is also necessary for both case 1 and case 2 in order to get the `O(log n)` complexity.

---

For case 1, note that `i` takes values `1, c, c2, c3, ..., clogc(n)`, so there are in total `log(n)` many iterations, and for each iteration there is a constant amount of work to be done (i.e. `O(1)` amount of work), so the total amount of work done is `log(n) * O(1) = O(log(n))`.

Similarly for case 2, `i` takes values `n, n / c, n / c2, n / c3, ..., , n / clogc(n)`, so there are in total `log(n)` many iterations and each iteration takes constant amount of time, so the total time complexity is `O(log(n))`.

For case 3, `i` takes values `2, 2c, (2c)c = 2c2, (2c2)c = 2c3, ..., 2clogc(log(n))`. The last term has to be less than or equal to `n`, and we have `2clogc(log(n)) = 2log(n) = n`, which justifies the value of our last term. So there are in total `logc(log(n))` many iterations, and each takes a constant amount of time to run, therefore the total time complexity is `O(log(log(n)))`.

Similarly for case 4, `i` takes values `n, n1/c, (n1/c)1/c = n1/c2, n1/c3, ..., n1/clogc(log(n))`, so there are in total `logc(log(n))` iterations and each iteration takes time `O(1)`, so the total time complexity is `O(log(log(n)))`.